# optimal stopping time problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, sde

I'm currently reading a [paper](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=82927) (*The Optimal Stopping Time for Selling an Asset When It Is Uncertain Whether the Price Process Is Increasing or Decreasing*, American Journal of Operations Research, March 2018)
about an optimal stopping time problem.

My issue is that I'm unable to see why $\sigma$ was added in the drift term of the process $dZ_t$. From what was explained to me, what the authors want to do is to get to the expression $(6)$. Which has the advantage of being a simple geometric brownian motion where we no longer have to deal with $\pi_t$. The same goes to $\phi_t$, the odds ratio, reducing thus the dimensionality of the problem.

If we want to reverse engineer the definition of $Z_t$, we know that we have something in the form: $d\bar{W}_t=dZ_t+c_tdt$ where $dZ_t$ is a Brownian motion under another measure $Q$. This actually defines $Z_t$ as
$dZ_t=-c_t dt+d \bar{W}_t$. Plugging this into $dX_t$ we obtain:
$dX_t/X_t = \sigma[(-\omega*\pi_t + \mu_2/\sigma + c_t)dt + dZ_t]$ where $\omega = (\mu_2-\mu_1)/\sigma$. We can now set $c_t = \omega*\pi_t$ to get rid of the $\pi_t$ term.

*However and for some reason* the drift term of the $dZ_t$ process (unnumbered equation after equation (3)) contains an additional $\sigma$! Can anyone please explain why.